# Display Ads from Android service

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I can display my ads like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                displayInterstitial();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 240000);
            }
        }, 100000);
```

How can i displayInterstitial() independent with activity?

That mean i want to show displayInterstitial() from any activity of my application.

Should i use service to display this? And if yes, how can i stop handler when my application in background.

Thank you

Comment: Create a base `Activity` with your ad code and extend it for each `Activity` in your app.

Comment: Should i cancel the handler in onPause?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use ads in my apps. Cancel the Handler in the base Activity wherever you'd normally cancel it. As long as the Activities which extend your base Activity call through to `super.onPause()` (or wherever you cancel the Handler) then it will work for all Activities.

Comment: Please answer this question, i will mark it as correct answer

Comment: I've expanded my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a 'base' `Activity` which includes the code for displaying your ads.

Example...

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {

    // Put the code for displaying the ads into methods in this
    // Activity following the guidelines from your ad provider

}
```

Once you've done that you simply need to extend your base `Activity` as follows...

```
public class FirstActivity extends MyBaseActivity {
    ...
}

public class SecondActivity extends MyBaseActivity {
    ...
}
```

If you need to you just have to call the `super` methods of the base `Activity` in order to turn on or turn off the ads.